# Returning a tuple from one method to another

Tags: c#, tuples, return

I have a lab where the guidelines are that I need to use a loop for the math portion of it so i created 2 methods one that consists of the math and the other that has the variables, the idea was to use a tuple and bring all the variable back into method main so I could present them in a table which is a requirment but when I use the return t1 it says cant change (double,double,etc) to double , not sure what id need to add to get this working any and all help is appreciated.

```
using System;

namespace _1012Lab3
{
    class Program
    {
        static double Thi(double temp1, double RH1) { double RH2 = (RH1 / 100); double THI = temp1 - 0.55 * (1 - RH2) * (temp1 - 58); return THI; }

        static double TempManage(double temp)
        {
            double THI40 = 0, THI50 = 0, THI60 = 0, THI70 = 0, THI80 = 0, THI90 = 0, THI100 = 0;
            double rh = 0;
            while (rh <= 101)
            {
                rh++;
                switch (rh)
                {
                    case 40:
                        THI40 = Thi(temp, rh);
                        Console.WriteLine(THI40);
                        continue;

                    case 50:
                        THI50 = Thi(temp, rh);
                        Console.WriteLine(THI50);
                        return THI50;

                    case 60:
                        THI60 = Thi(temp, rh);
                        Console.WriteLine(THI60);
                        return THI60;

                    case 70:
                        THI70 = Thi(temp, rh);
                        Console.WriteLine(THI70);
                        return THI70;

                    case 80:
                        THI80 = Thi(temp, rh);
                        Console.WriteLine(THI80);
                        return THI80;

                    case 90:
                        THI90 = Thi(temp, rh);
                        Console.WriteLine(THI90);
                        return THI90;

                    case 100:
                        THI100 = Thi(temp, rh);
                        Console.WriteLine(THI100);
                        return THI100;
                }

            }
            (double, double, double, double, double, double, double) t1 = (THI40, THI50, THI60, THI70, THI80, THI90, THI100);

            return t1;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // calculate THI(Temp- 0.55(1-Relative Humidity)(Temp -58))
            //relative humidity range 40% - 100%
            //temp range 60F - 100F
            //increments of 10
            // make a method for the formula?
            //THI = Tdb – [0.55 – (0.55 x RH/100)] x (Tdb – 58)
            //create loop that goes up in incremets of 10
            //while temp<10 
            // rh is 0-1 so for 60% humidity  60/100=0.6
            // test example works temp 60 ,RH 50(0.5) answer is 59.45
            //temp ranges 60,70,80,90,100
            //Rh ranges 40,50,60,70,80,90,100
            double temp = 0;
            double THI = 0;
            double rh = 0;
            double final = 0;

            double THI40 = 0, THI50 = 0, THI60 = 0, THI70 = 0, THI80 = 0, THI90 = 0, THI100 = 0;
            Console.WriteLine($"{THI40} {THI50} { THI60} {THI70} { THI80} { THI90} {THI100}");
            while (temp <= 100)
            {
                temp++;
                switch (temp)
                {
                    case 60:
                        final = TempManage(temp);
                        Console.WriteLine(final);
                        break;
                    case 70:
                        final = TempManage(temp);
                        break;
                    case 80:
                        final = TempManage(temp);
                        break;
                    case 90:
                        final = TempManage(temp);
                        break;
                    case 100:
                        final = TempManage(temp);
                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"| TEMP |                   Humidity                     |");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"|      |  40 |  50  |  60  |  70  |  80  |  90  |  100  |");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"|  60  |  40 |  50  |  60  |  70  |  80  |  90  |  100  |");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"|  70  |  40 |  50  |  60  |  70  |  80  |  90  |  100  |");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"|  80  |  40 |  50  |  60  |  70  |  80  |  90  |  100  |");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"|  90  |  40 |  50  |  60  |  70  |  80  |  90  |  100  |");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"|  100 |  40 |  50  |  60  |  70  |  80  |  90  |  100  |");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the return value of `TempManage` to be a `Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double, double>`. You can also consider to return an array instead (since there are cases you return only 1 element).

Comment: havent learned arrays yet ,but thank you

Comment: As already noted, the error is fairly clear… the method signature…  `static double TempManage(double temp) { …` … is returning a single `double` value and the variable `t1` doesn’t look like a “single” `double` value.

Comment: so would i make it  static Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double, double> TempManage(double temp)

Comment: That only creates the same problem with the other retuned values like… `return THI100;` … ? …

Comment: so how would you go about it then?

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger and step through your code to see what you code is doing. I am not following what your code is trying to do. And, fixing your current issue is something only you can answer… If you originally wanted to return a tuple, then why does the code return a single value in all the previous return statements?

Comment: To help, there are a couple of things you may want to rethink. Take a closer look at the code in the `ManageTemp` method. Specifically the `rh` variable which starts at zero (0)… Then a `while` loop is started like… `while (rh <= 101)` … ? … this is odd, but let us continue.

Comment: When the loop is entered, `rh` is incremented to 1. Then a `switch` statement is started with `rh` being the case value to match. Since 1 is not one of the `Case` conditions, then the code loops back up to the `while` loop and increments `rh` by 1 making it 2. This will happen exactly 49 times before `rh` becomes 50 and then the code returns the `Case` of 50 since 40 did not return any value. This code will ALWAYS do this same thing every time. It will NEVER get to the `Case` values of 60, 70, 80, 90 or 100.

Comment: The same odd `while` loop construct is used in the main method and in that case the value of `final` at the end will ALWAYS be the case 100 value. But this is irrelevant since the code does NOTHING with the `final` value anyway.

Comment: You need to go back to the drawing board and formulate a better approach as I am confident your current approach is not going to work. If you are learning, the debugger is your best friend… learn how to use it. It is designed just for helping you figure out what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended ways to return multiple values is to use a ValueTuple:

```
static (double THI40, double THI50)  TempManage(double temp)
```

However, your code using a loop and a switch just does not make any sense, you should just rewrite it as

```
var THI40 = Thi(temp, 40);
var THI50 = Thi(temp, 50);
...
return (THI40 , THI50)
```

when calling the method you can either use

```
var (thi40, thi50) = TempManage(temp);
```

or

```
var temps = TempManage(temp);
Console.WriteLine(temps.THI40);
```

Note that you should try to follow the standard [coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), i.e. avoid multiple statements on one line, follow capitalization rules for local variables etc.

Comment: i know using aloop there makes no sense but thats the guidlines off the project

Comment: @JGray I would very much question such guidelines. A professional developer should not just accept nonsensical requirements, especially not with regards to code style. It is possible they intend to evolve the code in some way where the loop makes sense, but such plans should be communicated, so you have some idea what the long term goal is.